# Do (or did) post offices in Singapore have a policy of attending to men with long hair last?

Tags: law, discrimination

I recently saw this photo on Facebook.  Is the contained claim true, that post offices in Singapore will attend to men with long hair last?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So it was reported in the news at the time (e.g. 1980):

> ### Long hair not fitting in in Singapore
>
> SINGAPORE (AP) - A government campaign against long hair on males has been extended … ([source](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1891&dat=19800613&id=hUJHAAAAIBAJ&sjid=jf0MAAAAIBAJ&pg=4278,2212586))
>
> ### Long Hair Frowned Upon In Singapore
>
> SINGAPORE (AP) - A five-year attempt to stamp out long hair here has not been successful but the campaign continues with much vigor. ([source](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1755&dat=19760208&id=eUk0AAAAIBAJ&sjid=L2cEAAAAIBAJ&pg=5546,3278787))

Apparently it started in the early 1970s according to [this article](http://singapore60smusic.blogspot.fr/2009/03/blog-post_24.html), which includes a sample poster:

[image]

Comment: This site has the poster.  Search it for "hair" http://remembersingapore.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/singapore-campaigns-of-the-past/